# EF Core migrations change name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

A colleague named a migration: `changed relatino on scanned objects`.
This gives the following output warning:

```
21>C:\[REDACTED]\Migrations\Migrations\20230202123158_changed relatino on scanned objects.cs(8,26,8,57): warning CS8981: The type name 'changedrelatinoonscannedobjects' only contains lower-cased ascii characters. Such names may become reserved for the language.
21>C:\[REDACTED]\Migrations\Migrations\20230202123158_changed relatino on scanned objects.Designer.cs(16,19,16,50): warning CS8981: The type name 'changedrelatinoonscannedobjects' only contains lower-cased ascii characters. Such names may become reserved for the language.
```

These migrations are already in the database.
How would i go about safely renaming this migration to suppress the warning message? The migration is already in the Db.

Using NET7 with EF7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename migration files without being worried about applied migration in DB because EF uses the passing name to [MigrationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationattribute?view=efcore-7.0) for `MigrationId`. If you open `20230202123158_changed relatino on scanned objects.Designer.cs` class, it should be decorated with the attribute with such a identifier

```cs
[Migration("20230202123158_changed_relatino_on_scanned_objects")]
```

After renaming files you can safely check if there are any pending migration or not?

```cs
var appliedMigrations = dbContext.GetService<IHistoryRepository>()
    .GetAppliedMigrations()
    .Select(m => m.MigrationId);

var total = dbContext.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>()
    .Migrations.Select(m => m.Key);

var hasPendingMigration = total.Except(appliedMigrations).Any();
```

If there wasn't any update, you're done otherwise you should manually update migration id in DB.